# Volume changes when mixing DMSO and water

Tags: mixtures, hydrogen-bond

Since I know that a mixture of 500ml $\ce{H_2O}$ and 500ml ethanol gives less than a liter of mixture I wonder how strong this effect is when mixing DMSO and $\ce{H_2O}$. I'd assume it's nonzero - but is it negligible?

Comment: See also [LeBel, R. G.; I. Goring, D. A. Density, Viscosity, Refractive Index, and Hygroscopicity of Mixtures of Water and Dimethyl Sulfoxide. _J. Chem. Eng. Data,_ **1962,** _7_ (1), 100–101.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/je60012a032)

Comment: follow up: do we expect this to be significantly different at 20°C, which is a more likely temperatur in real life...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that the density of the mixture is just the average of the individual densities, would get 1 litre of a mixture with a density of 1.04635 kg/l.
However, measured density ([1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/je60012a032), table 1) is 1.0682.

We thus expect to see a volume that is 0.9795 times the added individual volumes.

In this case: 0.9795 litres.

[LeBel, R. G.; I. Goring, D. A. Density, Viscosity, Refractive Index, and Hygroscopicity of Mixtures of Water and Dimethyl Sulfoxide. J. Chem. Eng. Data, 1962, 7 (1), 100–101](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/je60012a032)